# ufw мешает подключиться к docker контейнеру извне

Tags: docker, mongodb, docker-compose, firewall, ufw

При обращении к `http://ip:22351` извне, выдает ошибку

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to ip port 22361 after 21051 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Но если я отключаю ufw `ufw disable`, то я могу спокойно это делать.
Как мне обращаться к mongo, не отключая ufw?

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                 NAMES
608c08615365   abc-mongo   "/bin/sh -c 'mongod …"   20 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes   22361/tcp, 0.0.0.0:22361->27017/tcp   mongo
```

```
# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3'

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MongoRootPassword
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: $MongoDatabase
      MONGO_INITDB_USER: $MongoUserName
      MONGO_INITDB_PWD: $MongoUserPassword
      MONGO_REPLICA_HOST: $MongoHostName
      MONGO_REPLICA_PORT: 27017
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:22351:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb:
```

Comment: Добавляйте разрешение для входящих подключений для заданного порта.

Comment: @user7860670 `sudo ufw allow 22361/tcp`? Делал, не помогает

Comment: Порты только не путайте